# Elisp: call keymap from code?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here's a minimal snippet to get things going:

```lisp
(define-prefix-command 'foo)
(define-key foo "a" 'bar)
(define-key foo "b" 'baz)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'foo)
```

Now I can "call" the `foo` keymap when I press <kbd>C-M-r</kbd>.
But I wonder how I can do this from code, e.g. something like:

```
(funcall (lambda-from-keymap 'foo))
```

After this call, I expect the focus to be in the minibuffer, expecting either
<kbd>a</kbd>, or <kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>C-h</kbd> to be entered.
Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `read-key-sequence` and `lookup-key` to implement this:

```
(defun call-keymap (map &optional prompt)
  "Read a key sequence and call the command it's bound to in MAP."
  ;; Note: MAP must be a symbol so we can trick `describe-bindings' into giving
  ;; us a nice help text.
  (let* ((overriding-local-map `(keymap (,map . ,map)))
         (help-form `(describe-bindings ,(vector map)))
         (key (read-key-sequence prompt))
         (cmd (lookup-key map key t)))
    (if (functionp cmd) (call-interactively cmd)
      (user-error "%s is undefined" key))))
```

If you hit <kbd>C-h</kbd> `read-key-sequence` still waits for you to complete the sequence. I think you could simulate Emacs' normal behaviour by looping with `read-key` instead, it's a bit more involved though.

Use it like this:

```
(defun bar () (interactive) (message "you called bar"))
(defun baz () (interactive) (message "you called baz"))

(define-prefix-command 'foo)
(define-key foo "a" 'bar)
(define-key foo "b" 'baz)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'foo)

(defun call-foo ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Note: pass the symbol form of the keymap so we can give nice help
  (call-keymap 'foo "enter a foo command: "))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'call-foo)
```

Comment: Aha, it's just a matter of binding `help-form`. I also needed to change the calling convention to require the keymap as a symbol so as to get a nice help text: `(call-keymap 'foo)` instead of `(call-keymap foo)`

Comment: I don't understand this `(keymap (,map . ,map))` business

Comment: @Stefan Hmm, to be honest, I don't remember what I was thinking at the time. It looks like it matches the `(TYPE . BINDING)` form of a keymap element, so we're pretending the commands in `map` are bound under the prefix key `MAP` (i.e., which should be a symbol). Apparently this makes `describe-bindings` print something reasonable when you hit `C-h` at the `read-key-sequence` prompt.

Answer (score 3):

If the keymap is bound to a key sequence, you can invoke it by emulating the exact key sequence by setting `unread-command-events`:

```lisp
(setq unread-command-events
      (mapcar (lambda (e) `(t . ,e))
              (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-M-r"))
```

Comment: +1 because this is the simplest/easiest solution **so long as** 1) the keymap is bound in the current context at that known key sequence, and 2) you can afford to defer execution until the current command ends. But it won't work for e.g. `(with-selected-window another-window (run-command-bound-at "C-M-r"))`, because the window selection and active key maps will revert back before Emacs gets around to processing `unread-command-events` again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `foo` interactive. I did so using:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") (lambda () (interactive) ( foo)))
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the solution. `foo` isn't a function but a keymap, so `(foo)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @abo-abo yeah, I tried to replace `(foo)` by `(funcall (lambda-from-keymap 'foo))`, but I am getting an error message `Symbol's function definition is void: lambda-from-keymap`. And by the way I get the same error when I run `(funcall (lambda-from-keymap 'foo))`

Comment: `lambda-from-keymap` is the imaginary function that I would like to have:).
I was hoping someone would show me how to implement it.

Comment: @abo-abo Oh, I totally misundertood your question! but now I want to know how to do it as well!

Comment: here's something close to a solution: http://oremacs.com/2015/02/02/colorful-hydrae/